# Instruction Level Profiling: The Meaning of the Instruction Pointer?

Tags: performance, assembly, profiling, x86-64, low-level

When profiling code at the the assembly instruction level, what does the position of the instruction pointer really mean given that modern CPUs don't execute instructions serially or in-order?  For example, assume the following x64 assembly code:

```
mov RAX, [RBX];         // Assume a cache miss here.
mov RSI, [RBX + RCX];   // Another cache miss.             
xor R8, R8;        
add RDX, RAX;           // Dependent on the load into RAX.
add RDI, RSI;           // Dependent on the load into RSI.
```

Which instruction will the instruction pointer spend most of its time on?  I can think of good arguments for all of them:

- `mov RAX, [RBX]` is taking probably 100s of cycles because it's a cache miss.
- `mov RSI, [RBX + RCX]` also takes 100s of cycles, but probably executes in parallel with the previous instruction.  What does it even mean for the instruction pointer to be on one or the other of these?
- `xor R8, R8` probably executes out-of-order and finishes before the memory loads finish, but the instruction pointer might stay here until all previous instructions are also finished.
- `add RDX, RAX` generates a pipeline stall because it's the instruction where the value of `RAX` is actually used after a slow cache-miss load into it.
- `add RDI, RSI` also stalls because it's dependent on the load into `RSI`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CPUs maintains a fiction that there are only the architectural registers (RAX, RBX, etc) and there is a specific instruction pointer (IP).  Programmers and compilers target this fiction.

Yet as you noted, modern CPUs don't execute serially or in-order.  Until you the programmer / user request the IP, it is like Quantum Physics, the IP is a wave of instructions being executed; all so that the processor can run the program as fast as possible.  When you request the current IP (for example, via a debugger breakpoint or profiler interrupt), then the processor must recreate the fiction that you expect so it collapses this wave form (all "in flight" instructions), gathers the register values back into architectural names, and builds a context for executing the debugger routine, etc.

In this context, there is an IP that indicates the instruction where the processor should resume execution.  During the out-of-order execution, this instruction was the oldest instruction yet to complete, even though at the time of the interrupt the processor was perhaps fetching instructions well past that point.

For example, perhaps the interrupt indicates `mov RSI, [RBX + RCX];` as the IP, but the `xor` had already executed and completed; however, when the processor would resume execution after the interrupt, it will re-execute the xor.

Comment: Could you explain how hardware performance monitoring counters operate in that context? E.g. Linux has the `perf` subsystem that provides statistical profiling based on PMCs. Is the kernel just generating a high-frequency interrupt which then would - according to your very nice analogy - collapse the IP wave function and read out the PMCs, and would then assign the current values of that PMCs to the IP currently found (after wave function collapse)? And then reset the PMCs and resume from the interrupt?

Comment: So the same thing happens when a context switch happens? The OS will store the context which is at the oldest instruction not yet finished and will have to re-execute out-of-order executed ones?

Comment: Yes.  A context switch (generally) relies on a timer interrupt.  On any interrupt, hardware will give the OS the IP for the next instruction, so that the OS can resume the process's execution at that instruction.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good question, but in [*the kind of performance tuning I do*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771), it doesn't matter.
It doesn't really matter because what you're looking for is speed-bugs.
These are things that the code is doing that take clock time and that could be done better or not at all. Examples:
- Spending I/O time looking in DLLs for resources that don't, actually, need to be looked for.
- Spending time in memory-allocation routines making and freeing objects that could simply be re-used.
- Re-calculating things in functions that could be memo-ized.
... this is just a few off the top of my head

Your biggest enemy is a self-congratulatory tendency to say "I wouldn't consciously write any bugs. Why would I?" Of course, you know that's why you test software. But the same goes for speed-bugs, and if you don't know how to find those *you assume there are none*, which is a way of saying "My code has no possible speedups, except maybe a profiler can show me how to shave a few cycles."

In my half-century experience, there is *no code* that, as first written, contains no speed-bugs. What's more, there's an enormous *multiplier effect*, where every speed-bug you remove makes the remaining ones more obvious. As a contrived example, suppose bug A accounts for 90% of clock time, and bug B accounts for 9%. If you only fix B, big deal - the code is 11% faster. If you only fix A, that's good - it's 10x faster. But if you fix both, that's really good - it's 100x faster. Fixing A made B big.

So the thing you need most in performance tuning is to *find the speed-bugs, and not miss any*. When you've done all that, then you can get down to cycle-shaving.